# Combination of indivisible elements is indivisible (in abelian group)?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group (if really needed, you can impose additional restrictions, such as finitely generated or without torsion, but hopefully they are not needed).

An element $a$ is called indivisible if there is no element $a'$ such that $a=na'$ with $|n|\ne1$.

Let $a,b$ be linearly independent invidisible elements. Is it true that for any two mutually prime integers $m,n$, i.e., if $gcd(m,n)=1$, the element $(ma+nb)$ is indivisible?

From this, by recursion, it would hold that $\sum n_ia_i$ is indivisible when all $a_i$ are indivisible and $gcd(\{n_i\})=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider $G=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Z}$. If $(r,s)\in G$ and $n>0$, then $n(r,s)=(nr,ns)$ has second component in $n\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, for any rationals $x$ and $y$, the elements $a = (x,1)$ and $b=(y,-1)$ are indivisible.

Now take $m=n=1$; then $ma+nb = a+b = (x+y,0)$, which is in the divisible subgroup of $G$ and hence not indivisible.

Even with larger values of $m$ and $n$, you get an element of the form $(x+y,m-n)$, and this will be equal to $d(r,s)$ for some $(r,s)$ whenever $d|m-n$.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the same could be achieved with $G =\mathbb Z^2$, $a=(1,1)$, $b=(1,-1)$, then $a+b=(2,0)$, divisible, right?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh: It's not divisible, but it is not indivisible either. "Divisible" here means that for *every* $n$ there exists $a'$ such that $na'=a$. So "indivisible" is not the negation of "divisible".